# How to create AWS signed cookies with elixir?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, elixir, sha, signed

I've been trying to set up CloudFront with signed cookies using elixir. From what I learned the signature must use sha1 encoding. According to AWS in the terminal that would look like this:

`cat policy.json | openssl sha1 -sign CloudFront_Key.pem |base64 |tr '+=/' '-_~'`

I can't figure out how to do that in elixir. I've been looking into [this dependency](https://github.com/anoskov/rsa-ex) and tried using `:sha1` instead in it's `sign` method. I did read through [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html) and did see sha, not sha1. Is that how erlang calls it? (I have close to no knowledge about erlang). Tried `:sha` but I do not get the same key as in the terminal and it does not seem to work. I also noticed that base64 usually adds a few extra chars at the end than the terminal. Not sure what to do.. Resort to try using `System.cmd` ?

This is the AWS doc I'm following: [create & verify signed cookies](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cf-signed-cookies-s3-origin/) and [create signature for signed cookie](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-canned-policy.html#private-content-canned-policy-signature-cookies)

Comment: I think you need to use `public_key:sign/3`. Can you share a sample json and pem file with the expected output? I'll try it out with `public_key:sign/3`.

Comment: Sample pem http://www.filedropper.com/pk . The json content is just `{"Statement":[{"Resource":"https://mycloudfront.net/a.png","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":1512086400}}}]}` Do you get the same thing using :public_key? If so what command do you use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:public_key.sign/3` for this.

For reference,

```
$ cat pk.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
$ cat policy.json
{"Statement":[{"Resource":"https://mycloudfront.net/a.png","​Condition":{"DateLes​sThan":{"AWS:EpochTi​me":1512086400}}}]}
```

First, read the key:

```
iex(1)> key = File.read!("pk.pem") |> :public_key.pem_decode |> hd |> :public_key.pem_entry_decode
...
```

Then sign the data using `:public_key.sign/3`:

```
iex(2)> File.read!("policy.json") |> :public_key.sign(:sha, key) |> Base.encode64
"QjLmx3LASRb1zt9eW/EMywGMXB1SwX/0JrTnLOFulYjcRJ1dpacUZBB/AYI1zwaXPEQTgQ8crNDFgje6fqbLKoNwgcpE9mOK/RdDKi963ztJnD6EmtM60YbROSpjQ/LDupEYgipPNZbjCnRCJcqDX43BadbVR75G3B5mFmAwtRSPdslJ5irVnt9PjoDMdi9DYe1wGhgQkoym1tiKEyaTrH5lyrw+KPdAi1tpzuZ60ZEcQFJJbKqYYdA0SslbUFL71mdLLkQ9xz95JPNpsSY3ZJyJsKpRGFJuaL1aMsdNLxlLD91PpNW15FitBpBnAwuiiEfPrwU14zIxsfFszaM6KA=="
```

The output is identical to openssl:

```
$ cat policy.json | openssl sha1 -sign pk.pem | base64
QjLmx3LASRb1zt9eW/EMywGMXB1SwX/0JrTnLOFulYjcRJ1dpacUZBB/AYI1zwaXPEQTgQ8crNDFgje6fqbLKoNwgcpE9mOK/RdDKi963ztJnD6EmtM60YbROSpjQ/LDupEYgipPNZbjCnRCJcqDX43BadbVR75G3B5mFmAwtRSPdslJ5irVnt9PjoDMdi9DYe1wGhgQkoym1tiKEyaTrH5lyrw+KPdAi1tpzuZ60ZEcQFJJbKqYYdA0SslbUFL71mdLLkQ9xz95JPNpsSY3ZJyJsKpRGFJuaL1aMsdNLxlLD91PpNW15FitBpBnAwuiiEfPrwU14zIxsfFszaM6KA==
```

Comment: I've never read the key that way :o. Far as I could go was pem_decode. Trying it out now

Comment: Working. Thank you so much! While working on it I think I was also trying to do a `map |> Poison.encode()` instead of `File.read` on what I knew the content looks like, but that wasn't giving me `\n` at the end. That messed up the encoding more and also explains now the extra characters I was seeing when doing base64 encoding. Spend days on this. You rock!